# Symfony 5 ajax post form

Tags: ajax, symfony5

I need to make dynamic form in symfony 5 with ajax.
I make post request with axios on input value change on main route "/".
This route call my controller and i call dump() function for debug my request but i don't have any params on my request.

I looked in my network and my data is posted well. But I don't receive params on my request controller :/

On my view

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    cat = document.getElementById("article_category")
    token = document.querySelector("#article__token");
    title = document.querySelector("#article_title");

    cat.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        let form = document.querySelector("form")
        let data = {}

        data[title.getAttribute("name")] = title.value
        data[token.getAttribute("name")] = token.value
        data[cat.getAttribute("name")] = cat.value

        axios.post("https://127.0.0.1:8000/", data).then(res => {
            str = res.data
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
            console.log(doc);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    })
</script>
```

My Controller

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="article")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            dump($request);
        }

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('article/index.html.twig', [
            "form" => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

FormType

```
$builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('category')
            ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class);

        $builder->get('category')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                if ($form->getData()->getName() == "Cat 0") {
                    $form->getParent()->add('tag', EntityType::class, [
                        'class' => Tag::class,
                    ]);
                }
            }
        );
```